# password validation not matching, clearing all the fields.

Tags: validation, passwords

I have a form validation script all the validation work. but the fields clear up when the alert about the passwords not matching shows up? how can i avoid that?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function formValidator(){
// Make quick references to our fields
var FNAME = document.getElementById('FNAME');
var LNAME = document.getElementById('LNAME');
var EMAIL = document.getElementById('EMAIL');
var GENDER = document.getElementById('GENDER');
var ADDRESS = document.getElementById('ADDRESS');
var CONTACTNO = document.getElementById('CONTACTNO');
var PASSWORD = document.getElementById('PASSWORD');
var PASSWORD2 = document.getElementById('PASSWORD2');

// Check each input in the order that it appears in the form!
if(isAlphabet(FNAME, "Please enter only letters for your first name"))
{
    if(isAlphabet(LNAME, "Please enter only letters for last name"))
    {
        if(emailValidator(EMAIL, "Please enter a valid email address"))
        {
            if(madeSelection(GENDER, "Please Choose a Gender"))
            {
                if(isAlphanumeric(ADDRESS, "Numbers and Letters Only for Address"))
                {
                    if(isNumeric(CONTACTNO, "Please enter only numbers for Contact No."))
                    {
                        if(lengthRestriction(PASSWORD, 6))
                        {
                            if (PASSWORD2 != PASSWORD)
                            {
                            alert ("You did not enter the same new password twice. Please re-enter your password.");
                            return true;
                            }   
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

return false;

 }
```

i think that there is no problem with my other functions?

```
 function notEmpty(elem, helperMsg){
if(elem.value.length == 0){
    alert(helperMsg);
    elem.focus(); // set the focus to this input
    return false;
}
return true;
 }

 function isNumeric(elem, helperMsg){
var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;
if(elem.value.match(numericExpression)){
    return true;
}else{
    alert(helperMsg);
    elem.focus();
    return false;
}
 }

function isAlphabet(elem, helperMsg){
var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
if(elem.value.match(alphaExp)){
    return true;
}else{
    alert(helperMsg);
    elem.focus();
    return false;
}
 }

 function isAlphanumeric(elem, helperMsg){
var alphaExp = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
if(elem.value.match(alphaExp)){
    return true;
}else{
    alert(helperMsg);
    elem.focus();
    return false;
}
 }

 function lengthRestriction(elem, min){
var uInput = elem.value;
if(uInput.length >= min){
    return true;
}else{
    alert("Please enter atleast " +min+ " characters");
    elem.focus();
    return false;
}
}

function madeSelection(elem, helperMsg){
if(elem.value == "Please Choose"){
    alert(helperMsg);
    elem.focus();
    return false;
}else{
    return true;
}
 }

function emailValidator(elem, helperMsg){
var emailExp = /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/;
if(elem.value.match(emailExp)){
    return true;
}else{
    alert(helperMsg);
    elem.focus();
    return false;
}
 }


</script>
```

i guess that i'm doing this part wrong?? but i don't know how to fix it? please help.

```
if (PASSWORD2 != PASSWORD)
{
alert ("You did not enter the same new password twice. Please re-enter your password.");
return true;
}
```

Comment: My feeling says that it caused by how you submit the form. Please show me the page that triggering the validation. I suspect you did form submit there.

Comment: <form onsubmit='return formValidator()' >

Comment: also when i remove the code if (PASSWORD != PASSWORD) it works just fine.

Comment: Why do you return true and not false in that case?! Probably the form is submitted. Also it may be considered more user friendly not to use alerts but to use some red label instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to do something like:

    if (PASSWORD2.value == PASSWORD.value)
    {
      alert ("You did not enter the same new password twice. Please re-enter your password.");
      return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. i did it and as you said it was not send. how do you do that?

Comment: I was thinking, and the answer of your problem is more easier that I was doing. Is just change the operator "!=" to "==" sinal on if password.